# angularjs filter object by key and ng-model for firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

i have data like this in my firebase:

```
rootNode:{
    "key1":value1,
    "key2":value2,

  }
```

i am doing an ng-repeat when i get the data from async call

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in data |filter:searchText">{{key}}</li>
<ul>
```

The list does show up fine but it is not filtering the serachText.

i want the list to show key1,key2,etc and the filter should work on the keys.

Is something wrong with my data structure?

I can use array of objects but firebase does not link arrays so i am looking for a object based solution

Comment: angular filters works on values not on keys

Comment: are u asking filter on keys?

Comment: yes..if the user types key1..then the key1 show filer..i am not concerned with the value1

Comment: u can go through this  Example : (https://jsfiddle.net/dwcydgtv/2/)